# Build Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): Undefined mixin

Tags: primeflex

I'm trying to create a style class similar to the example at [Primeflex](https://primeflex.org/installation#reuseclasses)

This is a simple angular application on v16.9.1 with primeflex installed. I'm looking to reuse some settings for input fields.

Started off by updating styles.scss:

```
@import "primeflex/primeflex.css";

.label{
    padding-right: 20px;
}

@mixin myMix{
 @include styleclass('w-full')
}

.input{
    @include myMix    
}
```

And first build produced:

```
> ng build

✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Undefined mixin.
  ╷
8 │  @include styleclass('w-full')
  │  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src/styles.scss 8:2   myMix()
  src/styles.scss 12:5  root stylesheet

./src/styles.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Undefined mixin.
   ╷
11 │  @include styleclass('w-full')
   │  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  src/styles.scss 11:2  myMix()
  src/styles.scss 15:5  root stylesheet
```

Here is the list of packages.

```
├── @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.12
├── @angular/animations@16.2.12
├── @angular/cli@16.2.12
├── @angular/common@16.2.12
├── @angular/compiler-cli@16.2.12
├── @angular/compiler@16.2.12
├── @angular/core@16.2.12
├── @angular/forms@16.2.12
├── @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@16.2.12
├── @angular/platform-browser@16.2.12
├── @angular/router@16.2.12
├── @types/jasmine@4.3.6
├── jasmine-core@4.6.0
├── karma-chrome-launcher@3.2.0
├── karma-coverage@2.2.1
├── karma-jasmine-html-reporter@2.1.0
├── karma-jasmine@5.1.0
├── karma@6.4.3
├── primeflex@3.3.1
├── primeicons@6.0.1
├── primeng@16.9.1
├── rxjs@7.8.1
├── tslib@2.6.2
├── typescript@5.1.6
└── zone.js@0.13.3
```